# Kentico - Get absolute (full) url of image from custom page type

Tags: kentico

I have a custom page type for infographics with an "Image" field to select item from media library. I'd like to get the absolute URL of the Image in a transformation for RSS feed. The code below only generates the relative URL. I've tried adding GetAbsoluteUrl() in different ways but couldn't make it to work. Could you help? Thanks!

```
<description><%# EvalCDATA("Image") %></description>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it makes sense to just put the image URL inside the `<description>`. If this is what you really need, getting an absolute URL would look like this:

```asp
<description><%# GetAbsoluteUrl(Eval<string>("Image")) %></description>
```

If you want an *image tag* (wrapped in a `CDATA` tag), you can do the following:

```asp
<description><![CDATA[<img src="<%# GetAbsoluteUrl(Eval<string>("Image")) %>" />]]></description>
```

Comment: You're right! I do need the image tag. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Transformation methods](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/writing-transformations/reference-transformation-methods#Reference-Transformationmethods-URLsandpagelinks)

```
<%# GetAbsoluteUrl(EvalCDATA("Image")) %>
```

or if this is an attachment, i.e. GUID

```
<%# GetFileUrl("Image") %>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried that before posting the question and just tried again. But got the error: ...... error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for  CMS.Controls.CMSAbstractTransformation.GetAbsoluteUrl(string)' has some invalid arguments
Exception type: System.Exception  ..... Also error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'CMS.Controls.CMSAbstractTransformation.GetAbsoluteUrl(string)' has some invalid arguments
Exception type: System.Web.HttpCompileException ......

Comment: Can you post here the actual output of <%# EvalCDATA("Image") %>?
is it something like "~/images/somepicture.jpg" ?

Comment: Yes, the output is like you said, here's the full output:<![CDATA[~/images/infographic-12017.png]]>

Comment: <%# GetAbsoluteUrl(Eval("Image")) %> should work then